# No module named exceptions when using docker as ansible

Tags: docker, ansible

I am trying to test ansible in docker containers where I have assigned one docker container as "ansible-controller" and the rest two as target nodes. I am using a ssh-enabled ubuntu docker image to spawn the docker containers. below is the dockerfile :-

```
    FROM ubuntu:16.04

    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
    RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
    RUN echo 'root:Passw0rd' | chpasswd
    RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

    RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd
    ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"

    RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile
    EXPOSE 22

    CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]*
```

I have also installed "sshpass" and "ansible" packages in the controller container but when I am trying to test ansible module "ping" to the target I am facing the following issue :-

```
target1 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "failed": true,
    "module_stderr": "",
    "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/root/.ansi
ble/tmp/ansible-tmp-1586534281.47-159197676145489/ping\", line 44, in <module>\r
\n    import exceptions\r\nImportError: No module named 'exceptions'\r\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
    "parsed": false
}
```

Below is my inventory file :-

```
target1 ansible_host=172.17.0.3 ansible_ssh_pass=Passw0rd ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3.5
```

I am unable to solve this issue so asking for your assistance. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My bad..The target machine did not have python installed.